# Question about finding accuracy using k-nearest neighbor

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, knn, nearest-neighbor

I'm following this online course in Machine Learning, and I have to find the accuracy using k-nearest neighbors of different values (k = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11) for a dataset called tissue_gene_expression from the dslabs package in R.

This may be easy to some, but I'm relatively new to machine learning and programming and I have tried different things and already spent several days trying to figure out where I'm going wrong with this question.

I would appreciate any help to figure out where I'm going wrong?

I've tried to partition the data into training and test tests using createPartition. The x-values are a matrix, and I don't know if that has to do with the problem but it also looks like 'y' is a factor and that the function doesn't work with that.

This is the message I get when I type in my code:

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one

The code I've used is below.

```
library(dslabs)
data("tissue_gene_expression")
ks <- seq(1,11,2)
x <- tissue_gene_expression$x
y <- tissue_gene_expression$y

accuracy <- map_df(ks, function(k){
set.seed(1)

test_index <- createDataPartition(y, times = 1, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)
train_set_y <- y[-test_index]
test_set_y <- y[test_index]
train_set_x <- x[-test_index]
test_set_x <- x[test_index]

fit <- knn3(y ~ x, data = train_set_x, k = ks)
y_hat <- predict(fit, test_set_x, type = "class")
confusionMatrix(data = y_hat, reference = test_set_x)$overall["Accuracy"]
})
```

**I get this error message**

```
  Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one 
10.
eval(predvars, data, env) 
9.
model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x, data = train_set) 
8.
model.frame(formula = y ~ x, data = train_set) 
7.
eval(m, parent.frame()) 
6.
eval(m, parent.frame()) 
5.
knn3.formula(y ~ x, data = train_set, k = ks) 
4.
knn3(y ~ x, data = train_set, k = ks) 
3.
.f(.x[[i]], ...) 
2.
map(.x, .f, ...) 
1.
map_df(ks, function(k) {
    set.seed(1)
    test_index <- createDataPartition(y, times = 1, p = 0.5, 
        list = FALSE) ...
```

**Here you can see a bit of the dataset I'm using**

The class and the first part of x in the data set looks like this (haven't included them all as it's too long):

```
 class(x)
[1] "matrix"

x
                   MAML1      LHPP    SEPT10    B3GNT4  ZNF280D    SOX12
cerebellum_1    9.825680  8.327163  5.499382  8.692371 5.642305 6.254751
cerebellum_2    9.631247  8.542827  5.644292  8.833679 5.685083 6.289460
           C21orf62     PER3   HOXA10    HOXC5     BLVRB     ZIM2    HEMK1
cerebellum_1   5.840938 8.330565 5.520803 7.660495  7.669237 8.355588 7.336959
cerebellum_2   6.065646 8.263576 5.528077 7.569041  7.779377 8.647475 7.282120
```

And the class and first lines of y look like this:

```
class(y)
[1] "factor"

y
  [1] cerebellum  cerebellum  cerebellum  cerebellum  cerebellum  cerebellum 
  [7] cerebellum  cerebellum  cerebellum  cerebellum  cerebellum  cerebellum 
 [13] cerebellum  cerebellum  cerebellum  cerebellum  cerebellum  cerebellum
```

Comment: can you post the trace of error

Comment: Are these functions from the caret package? Also, `train_set` appears to be missing.

Comment: Yes, the functions are from the caret package! 
Regarding the train_set I have split both x's and y's into training and test sets, as I was told this was necessary due to the features being a matrix... However I am not sure if I'm supposed to use cbind() to combine train_set_x and train_set_y and the same for the test sets?

 @RomanLuštrik

Comment: @joyaza. I've updated my post now to show the trace of error (I assume this is what you mean by posting the trace of error, but please check)